# TextView that gets Value from SharedPreferences shows nothing, though there should be default values

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am having an issue with `SharedPreferences` that is kind of weird.

I have an `Activity` that holds a `Fragment` in a `ViewPager`. The fragment shows an icon and text. You can change the icon (check mark or cross, check mark is default) and text displayed in this fragment from another activity. The data is then transferred to the Fragment Container Activity with an intent.

Now I want to save the text and chosen icon, so the fragment is shown with the same text and icon, even when you close the app and restart it later.

So I tried to achieve this with `SharedPreferences`, but when I tried it, my fragment showed me no text and the false icon, though I have default values set and the icon is always the cross, no matter what it was before though the default icon should be the check mark.

I am saving the values in `onCreateView()` of my Fragment when it is created with the data the user inputted in the activity before.

**Saving:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

            Bundle bundle = getArguments();

            String city = bundle.getString("city");
            String country = bundle.getString("country");
            int ok = bundle.getInt("ok");

            TextView cityText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_name);
            TextView countryText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
            ImageView shownIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ok_bad_icon);

            cityText.setText(city);
            countryText.setText(country);

            if(ok == 1){
             shownIcon.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.checkmark_icon, null));
            }else{
                shownIcon.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.bad_icon, null));
            }

            editor.putString("city", city);
            editor.putString("country", country);
            editor.putInt("okBad", ok);
            editor.putString("saved", "Yes");

            editor.apply();
```

Then, I am getting the values in `onCreate()` of my Activity that holds the Fragment:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
String storedSave = sharedPref.getString("saved", "no");

    if (storedSave.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){

    String storedCity = sharedPref.getString("city", "berlin");
    String storedCountry = sharedPref.getString("country", "germany");
    int storedOkBad = sharedPref.getInt("okBad", 1);

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();

        StatusFragment savedFragment = new StatusFragment();

        extras.putString("city", storedCity);
        extras.putString("country", storedCountry);
        extras.putInt("okBad", storedOkBad);

        savedFragment.setArguments(extras);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(savedFragment, extras.getString("city"));
    }
```

I searched for answers in different questions here on stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me, like:

[Cannot get value from sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306908/cannot-get-value-from-sharedpreferences)

[Shared Preferences get lost after shutting down device or killing the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803838/shared-preferences-get-lost-after-shutting-down-device-or-killing-the-app)

[Shared Preferences reset data when app is force closed or device is restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353900/shared-preferences-reset-data-when-app-is-force-closed-or-device-is-restarted)

[SharedPreferences keep getting default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157963/sharedpreferences-keep-getting-default-value)

[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values?rq=1)

I also tried with `Log.w()` and `Toast.makeText()` to print city's value, but nothing is ever shown, like if it is skipped entirely, but why do I have a `Fragment` in my `Activity` then after restart when this is skipped and it is not added?

And do I have to use `edit().putString().apply()` when editing or can I just add the value with `editor.putString()` even when it exists already?

Sorry if I it is perhaps something trivial, but I haven't worked with Fragments much and I am using `SharedPreferences` the first time now.

I would be grateful for every helpful answer.

Comment: initialize shred Preference this way  preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("Your shared Pref name ", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: @Himani, there is no problem in doing that as `getPreferences` _simply calls the underlying getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this activity's class name_

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question. How do you intiialize the shared preference in the activity that holds the fragment? How do you initialize and write to it in the other activities that you mentioned?

Comment: I added the initialization, in the activity the user can edit, i use an intent, no shared preferences

Comment: I tried to replace _getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)_ with _getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.fragmentdata.myapp.www", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)_ but always get the same result, only default values :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved now. I had to use `getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.fragmentdata.myapp", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);` and some of my variables in the bundles and preferences got mixed up. I have corrected this and now it works fine :) Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

call `getActivity()` in `onActivityCreated()` method of fragment.
In `onCreateView()` may be it return null context.Please check and move your code in `onActivityCreated()` method.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `SharedPreference` initialization like this and call `getActivity()` in `onActivityCreated()` :

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity())
```

Its recommended to do `apply()` rather than `commit()`. After editing changes, call:

```
editor.apply()
```

Comment: Thank you for the apply() hint, but unfortunately it doesn't change anything of the result i get :/

Answer (score 0):

On observing your code I noticed that there is a mismatch in the key.

> while saving in bundle you have used key - okBad

```
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    ....
    extras.putInt("okBad", storedOkBad);
```

> while retrieving in fragment you have used key - ok

```
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    ...
    int ok = bundle.getInt("ok");
```

So please rectify it first.

Comment: "ok" is the key of the variable i pass from the activity where the user edits the data, okBad is the key that i want to use in my shared preferences

Comment: @boehmP in the onCreate of Activity you posted, while creating bundle you have used "okBad" as key. And in the onCreateView of the fragment you are first extracting from bundle wherein you have used "ok" as the key. Please check it once again. If you have posted it incorrectly then rectify your question. Here I am not even mentioning shared preferences. I am just referring to the bundle that you have used as argument.